# Is it safe to share my hostname

Tags: network, linux, network-scanners

I am using GNU/Linux. Sometimes, I copy/paste code from the terminal (like user@hostname ..) to put it in a forum thread or a blog ..etc And I was always wondering that it is better to hide it .

Is it safe ? What risks may I encounter when I share my local hostname when using a regular internet connection  ?

Comment: My hostname is `localhost`.

Comment: I wouldn't share it if it isn't yours (ie, if a friend sends you a screenshot and you post it), because that has the potential to lead to legal complications. If an attacker on your network wants your hostname, he can get it fairly easily (in most cases).

Answer (score 4):

As a private individual, unless your hostname is `myPassWordIs123` and your password is `123`, then you really have nothing to worry about. Here's a screenshot from my main everyday-use laptop:

[image: my_host_name]

**However,** in corporate environment, hostnames usually hint at the functionality or the role of the server/machine. They might even provide some information that allows attacker to gain a deeper understanding of how the corporate network is designed and implemented.

After securing your machine with proper firewall rules, an anti-virus, common-sense usage practices, etc., then it might be beneficial to add a layer of obscurity and vagueness to your system.

**Bottom line is:** In your case, I wouldn't really worry about it.

Comment: Well in your anonymized "some" case there is not a lot of information to be exposed - that is true.
On the other hand you might use that username on a to the internet connected device et voila. Also if you get used to this behaviour you might just get so used to it that you also do this in a corporate environment, without really noticing it. So I stick to the paranoid side ;)

Answer (score 2):

It depends on how paranoid you are...

It certainly increases exposure of your environment or might attract more script kiddies etc. that use search engines like google to find such information. It might also help an attacker since it's easier when you already know the host- and usernames of your potential victim.

I for myself try to avoid to expose anything publicly that does not need to be exposed. This is the "need to know" principle applied to the internet.

So very specifically I would recommend you to not expose information such as host- or usernames or anything alike to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

As said before. It depends on how paranoid your are. In most cases, there is no consequences to disclose your username and the directory path to a specific file unless you don't want anyone to infer your identity. This is the case when you are working for an organization, a lab or a company and you don't want your co-worker or supervisor find out that you have posted this question.